# What is the correct conjugation (present, indicative) of “essayer” ?

Tags: conjugaison

I've looked up conjugation of “essayer” and two different sources have given me two different suggestions:

According to [this source](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Conjugaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais/essayer), one would pronounce “j'essaye” as “ʒ‿esɛj”.

According to the [other source](http://www.audiofrench.com/verbs/essayer_1.htm), one would pronounce it as “ʒ‿ese”.

I would like to ask which pronunciation is the correct one.
Or, if they are both correct, which is “more usual” and which is “less usual”.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both *j'essaie* pronounced /ʒ‿esɛ/ or /ʒ‿ese/ and *j'essaye* pronounced /ʒ‿esɛj/ are correct.

The former looks to be more frequently written but I'm not sure the same is true for spoken French where both might be equally used. In any case, I do not make a difference between these forms.